# Sweetalert2 - change displayed text dynamically - Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, sweetalert2

How could I change the text after I get the response asynchronously?

```
  var swText = "<h3>Importiranje kvota, molimo sačekajte...</h3>";
  swal({ html: swText });
  swal.showLoading();
  this.koloService.importExcelFileWithOdds(this.brojKola, fileList)
      .subscribe(
          data => { swText = "<h3>Importiranje završeno!</h3>"; swal.hideLoading(); },
          error => {  swText = "<h3>Importiranje završeno!</h3>"; swal.hideLoading(); });
```

Also, how could I hide the progress alert after I get the response from server?
The progress alert looks like this while the data is being imported:
[image]

And after I get the response from the server, progress alert doesn't hide, there is just an OK button which will close the alert - I want it to close as soon as I get the response from the server.
[image]

Comment: "destroying the initial swal and creating a new one in your data and error response handling part of your response" is an option for your case?

Comment: Could use that I guess in this use case, but is there a functionality to change the text without destroying the swal?

Comment: @ŽeljkoKrnjić any luck, i am having similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

Update (2022): use `Swal.update()` method:

```js
Swal.fire('After mignight I will turn into a pumpkin')
swal.showLoading()

// change the title after 2 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  Swal.update({ title: 'I am a pumpkin now!' })
  Swal.hideLoading()
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

---

There are all kinds of getters for accessing different parts of SweetAlert2: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#methods

You are looking for `Swal.getTitle()`:

```js
Swal.fire('After mignight I will turn into a pumpkin')
swal.showLoading()

// change the title after 2 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  Swal.getTitle().textContent = 'I am a pumpkin now!'
  Swal.hideLoading()
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: if you need to update the content (not just the title), use `Swal.getHtmlContainer().textContent = content;`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer has nothing about Angular2 but a simple solution to keep in mind, in Swal options you can do this

```
confirmButtonText: (() => {
   if (your_data) {
     return "something"
   } else return "something else"
})()
```